# Get field names on unchecked checkboxes

Tags: php, html

I created an HTML application form for my employer so that applicant's can apply online. However, I'm running into some issues with the PHP bit. I'd like for it to send me an email containing ALL of the forms field names along with their values (even if the value is left blank). It needs to be in this specific format so that I can quickly 'convert' that data programmatically from the email into an HCL Notes form.

However, when a checkbox on my HTML form is left unchecked, it is not sent to the $_POST array at all, which then obviously ends up breaking the bit that converts it as it can't find the correct field names.

I know this is a strange and very specific issue, but does anyone have any ideas as to how I can go about this successfully?

My PHP code currently (removed the parameters at the top for privacy):

```
<?php session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Results</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
//--------------------------Set these paramaters--------------------------

// Subject of email sent to you.
$subject = '';
   
// Your email address. This is where the form information will be sent.
$emailadd = '';

// Where to redirect after form is processed.
$url = '';

// Makes all fields required. If set to '1' no field can not be empty. If set to '0' any or all fields can be empty.
$req = '0';
  
$time = time();

// --------------------------Do not edit below this line--------------------------
$text = "Results from form:\n\n";
$space = ' ';
$line = '
';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();
  
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
   
   // handle the error accordingly with your other error checking
   // or you can do something really basic like this
   die('The code you entered was incorrect.  Go back and try again.');
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   if ($key != "captcha_code"){
       $j = strlen($key);
       if ($j >= 40){echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 39 characters";die;}
       $j = 40 - $j;
       for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++)
       {$space .= ' ';}
       $value = str_replace('\n', "$line", $value);
       $conc = "{$key}:$space{$value}$line";
       $text .= $conc;
       $space = ' ';
   }
}
$text .= 'END OF APPLICATION';

mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: ');
echo '<script>alert("Application successfully submitted.");</script>';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's how the emails look, I need it to be just like this but with ALL fields regardless of if they have values or not:

[image: Email Format]

Comment: Don't ask the browser for information you already have. What if the request includes made up fields, will you send them too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array that lists all the fields that should be in the email. Then instead of looping through `$_POST`, loop through that array. Display the corresponding `$_POST` field if it's filled in, otherwise show a blank value.

```
$fields = ['ReasonForReferral', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', ...];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $conc .= "$field: " . (isset($_POST[$field]) ? str_replace($_POST[$field], "\n", $line) : '') . $line;
}
```